# Suspend doesn't work 1st time but does second time

Tags: 14.04, suspend

First time I suspend, tries to suspend but then comes back to life. Second time works (usually, not always). It is hard to reproduce, every time I see it not suspending and then try again it works as it should. Below is syslog output around the time it happens. See anything that is causing the issue?

**First time**

`Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one anacron[4250]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one anacron[4250]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2016-02-23
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one dbus[693]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one dbus[693]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one dbus[693]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one dbus[693]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one CRON[4087]: (elijah) CMD (/home/elijah/.oh-my-fish/custom/homeshick_backup.fish > /dev/null 2>&1)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): taking down device.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): cleaning up...
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.548085] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.548080] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.548076] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.548072] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.548067] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.548062] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.548056] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.542861] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one wpa_supplicant[1702]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:15:ff:9b:74:04 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one dnsmasq[2355]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one kernel: [67256.520251] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:15:ff:9b:74:04 by local choice (reason=3)
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Received packet from invalid interface.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.4.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.4 on wlan0.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::224:d7ff:feac:c9c8.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::224:d7ff:feac:c9c8 on wlan0.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Registering new address record for fe80::224:d7ff:feac:c9c8 on wlan0.*.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::224:d7ff:feac:c9c8.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2600:1017:b806:d0f4:224:d7ff:feac:c9c8.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1017:b806:d0f4:224:d7ff:feac:c9c8 on wlan0.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1017:b806:d0f4:e458:1938:a989:e1fc on wlan0.
Feb 23 19:08:01 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1048
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one whoopsie[1242]: offline
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'sleeping') [37]
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one kernel: [67255.406679] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 55 for MSI/MSI-X
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (eth0): taking down device.
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (eth0): cleaning up...
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> sleeping or disabling...
Feb 23 19:08:00 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)`

**Second time**

`Feb 23 19:21:26 gaia-one kernel: [68059.284945] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Feb 23 19:21:26 gaia-one kernel: [68059.251312] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one anacron[15187]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one anacron[15187]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2016-02-23
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one dbus[693]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one dbus[693]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one dbus[693]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one dbus[693]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): taking down device.
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): cleaning up...
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one kernel: [68055.992511] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one kernel: [68055.992507] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one kernel: [68055.992504] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one kernel: [68055.992500] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one kernel: [68055.992496] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one kernel: [68055.992492] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one kernel: [68055.992485] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one dnsmasq[2355]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one kernel: [68055.987155] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.4.
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.4 on wlan0.
Feb 23 19:21:23 gaia-one wpa_supplicant[1702]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:15:ff:9b:74:04 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one kernel: [68055.955042] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:15:ff:9b:74:04 by local choice (reason=3)
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::224:d7ff:feac:c9c8.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::224:d7ff:feac:c9c8 on wlan0.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Registering new address record for fe80::224:d7ff:feac:c9c8 on wlan0.*.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::224:d7ff:feac:c9c8.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2600:1017:b806:d0f4:224:d7ff:feac:c9c8.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1017:b806:d0f4:224:d7ff:feac:c9c8 on wlan0.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2600:1017:b806:d0f4:224:d7ff:feac:c9c8.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2600:1017:b806:d0f4:e458:1938:a989:e1fc.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one avahi-daemon[846]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1017:b806:d0f4:e458:1938:a989:e1fc on wlan0.
Feb 23 19:21:22 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5186
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one whoopsie[1242]: offline
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'sleeping') [37]
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one kernel: [68054.855480] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 55 for MSI/MSI-X
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (eth0): taking down device.
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (eth0): cleaning up...
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> sleeping or disabling...
Feb 23 19:21:21 gaia-one NetworkManager[1017]: <info> sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)`

Comment: Argh, will try to fix the line break issue in a bit. On a train, need to get off train right now.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, my system is doing the same.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just live with it.